# Survival plot using autoplot (survMisc) with grey scale

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I have been trying to plot the survival function using the `autoplot` function in package `survMisc`. So far its good, the plot is fine, but the problem is I cannot use `scale_color_grey` to use the grey color scale.

The code is :

```
   autoplot(fit.bygroup, plotTable=TRUE, divideTime=1,legendLabs=c("group1", "group2"),  lty=c(1,2),geom_line(size=2))+ scale_color_grey()
```

I guess the problem is this `autoplot` is creating a blank object... Is there any way I can change them in to grey scale colors? Or what if I want a black and white background?

```
    p<- autoplot(fit.bygroup, plotTable=TRUE, divideTime=1,legendLabs=c("group1", "group2"),  lty=c(1,2),geom_line(size=2))
```

This p is actually `NULL`

Comment: Yup thanks finally I actually used the plain plot function. But I think your answer is perfect. Yup ! Its true that I am new in Stackoverflow , but Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the code for the `autoplot` function used by `survMisc`. You find a very nice post on how to view source code [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function/19226817#19226817).

Type `autoplot` in console.

```
autoplot
# ...snip
# UseMethod("autoplot")
# ...snip
```

`UseMethod("autoplot")` means that `autoplot` is an `S3` method. Then we can use `methods` to list available methods.

```
methods(autoplot)
# [1] autoplot.default* autoplot.survfit  autoplot.zoo
```

Type `autoplot.survfit` in console.

```
autoplot.survfit
```

Copy code to an editor.

**Change colour scale**:
Search for 'scale_col' and you will find three instances of:

```
scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Dark2",
                    guide = guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 3))
```

Replace them with:

```
scale_colour_grey(guide = guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 3))
```

**Change background colour**
In the second last code section:
Replace `print(g1)` with `print(g1 + theme_classic())` (or any other `theme` you like)
Replace `grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(g1 + theme(legend.position = "none"),` with `grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(g1 + theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = "none")`,

Save the updated function with a new name, e.g. `autoplot.survfit2`.

Try it on first example in `?survMisc::autoplot`

```
data(kidney, package = "KMsurv")
s1 <- survfit(Surv(time = time, event = delta) ~ type, data = kidney)
autoplot.survfit2(s1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, I tried to change the source code.....its working but I think there are some other issues that I need to solve, but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As of version `0.4.2` this is a bit less 'hackey'.
`autoplot.survfit` now returns a `table` and a `plot` in a list. 
These can be further modified as desired before combining them using `autoplot.tableAndPlot` as follows:

```
data(kidney, package = "KMsurv")
s1 <- survfit(Surv(time = time, event = delta) ~ type, data = kidney)
library(survMisc)
tap1 <- autoplot(s1)
for (i in seq_along(tap1)){
    tap1[[i]] <- tap1[[i]] + scale_colour_grey(guide = guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 3)) + theme_classic()
    }
autoplot(tap1)
```

giving:

[image]

Or to modify the plot alone, something like:

```
p1 <- autoplot(s1)$plot
p1 +
    scale_colour_grey(guide = guide_legend(keywidth = 3, keyheight = 3)) +
    theme_classic()
```

Comment: Glad to be of service.